# jQuery - On Select Option Event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make it so when somebody selects a certain option from my list it will trigger an event. I know you are supposed to use the .change event but that isn't working for me.

Checkout the code below.

Select:

```
$co1 = array("English", "Math", "Science", "History");
for($c=1;$c<5;$c++){
    echo '<select name="c'.$c.'" id="course'.$c.'" class="selectpicker"><option selected="selected" id="course'.$c.'" value="course'.$c.'" name="'.$c.'">Course '.$c.'</option>';
    foreach ($co1 as &$cl1){
        echo '<option value="'.$cl1.'" name="'.$cl1.'">'.$cl1.'</option>';  
    }
    echo '</select>';
}
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
    $('#course1').change(function(){
        $("#course2 option[value='Math']").each(function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    })
</script>
```

I basically used PHP to make it so there are four different select options with the same options but different values for a grading system. I want to use this script to make it so when you select Math for the first course it will remove it from the list in the other 3 courses.

Any ideas how this would work? I'm up for suggestions on other ways to do this.

Comment: The PHP has nothing to do with this question. Post the rendered HTML please.

Comment: `$("#course2 option[value='Math']").remove()` should work fine.

Comment: @tymeJV it does work, but the event doesn't work... I'll post a fiddle.

Comment: I see your `select` `option` is not standard html tag

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RnWq3/

Comment: What should happen if I change the first select and then change it again? Both options would be removed from the second select.

Comment: You're correct @j08691, and that is what I mean. I want to make it so that each time you select an element it will remove it from all the other ones and add it back if you select a different one. Thats why I thought the change event could work, on change reset them to default and then remove from others.

Answer (score 0):

Use `delegation`

```
$('body').delegate('#course1','change',function(){
    $("#course2 option[value='Math']").each(function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
})
```

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("body").on("change","#course1",function () {
     $("#course2").find("option[value='Math']").remove();
});
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/RnWq3/8/)

Comment: This doesn't work for some reason :/ I am using the latest jQuery. The console does return something though. "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead."

Comment: It is not happening because you have not used `<select><option>..` in your HTML. It shows `<li><a>` structure. Theerefore, `change()` event is not triggered.

Comment: it doesn't show <li><a> structure, view the source code of the page. I have set <select><option>.

Comment: I printed it to the page using PHP, rather than HTML because I used a for loop.

Comment: @user2812028 - The problem seems to be that what exists on the rendered page is a series of divs and buttons in addition to your selects. Also, the jQuery you have isn't inside a document ready call. This appears to be a result of some bootstrap-select script you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Attribute `name` and `id` just for only `select` tag. [Open this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) to see standard select option html tag.
If you do that, you have two same id there. `<select>`, and your first `<option>`.

try to change your PHP become :

```
$co1 = array("English", "Math", "Science", "History");
for($c=1;$c<5;$c++){
    echo '<select name="c'.$c.'" id="course'.$c.'" class="selectpicker">
             <option selected="selected" value="course'.$c.'">Course '.$c.'</option>';
             foreach ($co1 as &$cl1){
                echo '<option value="'.$cl1.'">'.$cl1.'</option>';  
             }
    echo '</select>';
}
```

Comment: This didn't fix it. It still doesn't remove math from the second selection.

Answer (score 0):

This is the shortest I could come up with:

```
$('#course1').change(function () {
    $('#course2').find('option:gt(0)').remove().end().append($(this).find('option:gt(0)[value!=' + $(this).val() + ']').clone())
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/RnWq3/20/)**

Comment: That works perfectly with plain HTML. Not sure why it doesn't work in my document :/ Checkout my latest comment on @Hiral's answer, I have a link to the full document. If you could try to find the issue I'd be very greatful :)

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors when you try to use my code?

Comment: BTW, why in your pastebin example are you including jQuery twice?

Comment: I guess I missed that part. And yes, it only shows 1 error "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead."

Answer (score 0):

this will hide the option from course2 if same is selected as course1 and show if user selects  another one in course1

```
$('#course1').change(function () {
  var val = $(this).val()
        
  if($('#course2').val()==val)                
    $('#course2').val($('#course2').children('option:first').val())
        
  $("#course2 option").each(function () {

   if ($(this).val() == val) 
     $(this).hide();  //change this line to $(this).remove() to remove permanently  
                     //and remove the else part below
   else 
     $(this).show()
        
 });
 })
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/RnWq3/19/)

**Note** that after removing completely you will not be able to show it again hence i will recommend using `show` and `hide` on change of course1

Comment: Thankyou! That is exactly what I needed, but this doesn't work in my document for some reason. :/ Maybe I am including the wrong jQuery library? But if I were than it would say I have the wrong one. The console prints this error though.

Comment: event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Comment: @user2812028 this is a warning not an error it has nothing to do with the code.I think problem is somewhere else in your document. Is your php producing correct html output?

Comment: Yes, it is. Atleast I believe so.

Comment: @user2812028 you have to be sure about this. Just right click the element and choose inspect element option from the context menu and observe closely every tag(opening, closing,id, value etc) in the console.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got right what you want to do. Try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RnWq3/27/)

You could just `.hide()` the option which matches the current selected and to show the before hidden again just `.show()` the current `:hidden` elements?

```
$('#course1').change(function(){
    var sel = $(this).val(); 
    $("#course2 option:hidden").show();
    $("#course2 option[value='"+sel+"']").each(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });    
});
```